# How do you properly update a mysql field with NULL?

Tags: mysql, null

How does one properly update a mysql field with a NULL value when using a variable in the sql query?

I have a variable called $timestamp.  When it's set to `date( Y-m-d h:i:s )` I have to wrap it in quotes because I'm passing a string in my mysql query.  When $timestamp is set to NULL, the database query contains `''` as the value for $timestamp and the field updates to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.  It's important to keep this field as NULL to show that the process has never been run before.

I don't want to use now() because then my sql statement is not in sync with my class variable $timestamp.

I don't want to set $timestamp to 'NULL' because then that variable is not accurate.  It's no longer NULL, it's set to a string that contains the word NULL.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, problem #1 is you're using SQL-string-building for queries. Don't do that (without a *really* good reason ... and then, don't do that). Use placeholders (or whatever ORM/framework of choice that doesn't require SQL-string-building). Not only will this problem "go away", but so will [a number of unexpected] injection-attack vulnerabilities.

Comment: I am not using a framework but could use PHP PDO. Will that solve this issue? I've used active record before, but never PDO.

Comment: [PDO does indeed support placeholders](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Positional-and-Named-Placeholders-P551.html) -- as does [mysqli](http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/) (although I dislike the mysqli approach), so there are at least two "standard" options available.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a lot of research, I've found that this is a well known problem with no good solution if you are writing your sql queries outright.

The correct solution is to use a database abstraction layer like [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) ( for PHP ), or Active Record ( used in frameworks like Codeignitor and Ruby on Rails ).

Answer (score 2):

The correct SQL syntax to set a column to NULL is:

```
  UPDATE Table SET Column = NULL WHERE . . .
```

(note the lack of quotes around the literal NULL).

Are you performing this UPDATE using SQL or using some kind of framework?  If a framework, it should recognize NULL values and pass them to the database correctly for you.